# How do I manage changes I don't want to push in git?

Tags: git

Sometimes I need to make changes to my local tree that I never want to push.  These might just be hacks to a script that runs the tests.  While I have this change in my local tree I may commit other real changes.

The problem:

- If I don't commit the hack then I have to be careful using `commit -a`
- If I don't commit the hack then it is hard to see if I've made a change I do want to commit to the same file.
- If I do commit the hack then I have to be careful not to push it.

Right now I'm committing the hacks with commit descriptions reminding me not to push them.  Then as I work and accumulate real changes I rebase the hacks to the HEAD of my branch.

Is there a better way to manage changes like this?

Comment: Are you aware of 'STASH' capabilities in GIT?

Comment: `git commit --amend` is what you might be looking for in your case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such possibility in git to ignore some changes in a file but keep it tracked for other changes.
Generally such kind of problem should be solved by configuration of your application. I mean if you have hacks, they shouldn't be hardcoded like that (don't know what language you do use, so it's some pseudo-code):

```
someMethod() {
   doWork();
   dirtyHack();
   doSomeOtherWork();
}
```

You'd better have a config file to describe whether hacks should be executed in the current configuration. So code may be modified like this:

```
someMethod() {
   doWork();
   if (readConfig().isDirtyHacksEnabled()) {
       dirtyHack();
   }
   doSomeOtherWork();
}
```

This approach allow you to have different config files on your machine and on a remote server (or wherever you want). 
And this particular config file should be ignored in git using the command:

```
git update-index --skip-worktree <path_to_file>
```

So you can keep track of your script files changes in git, while hacks be enabled only on your machine.
Do not confuse `--skip-worktree` with `--assume-unchanged`. 
When you set the latest flag you promise git not to do any changes, so git can skip checking index of the file and save some time if the file is huge or filesystem is slow.

Comment: I guess this is the answer: "There is no such possibility in git to ignore some changes in a file but keep it tracked for other changes."  Thanks for the suggestion to use configuration to manage the hacks.  I think that's a great technique in some cases but not really what I want for my immediate situation.  I really just don't want the code checked in.

Answer (score 2):

Use `--assume-unchanged` to mark files to be (temporarily) ignored for commit:

```
git update-index --assume-unchanged <file>
```

Then you can unmark with:

```
git update-index --no-assume-unchanged <file>
```

Answer (score 0):

Stash them using: git stash
Then you can make real changes, commit and later unstash the hack changes if you want